# netstat show a listen port but pid don't exist and can't find it with lsof

Tags: osx, netstat, lsof

I am running macOS(0.13.6) and while trying to test [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/), I get a warning that port `0.0.0.0:655` is already in use.

This is the output I get from `netstat`:

```
 $ sudo netstat -anv -p udp
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address Foreign Address  (state) rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid
udp4       0      0  *.655         *.*                      196724   9216  33103      0
```

I am trying also `sudo lsof -i :655` but can't find what process is using port 655.

I found a similar question: https://serverfault.com/q/311009/94862 in where the solution seems to be related to `NFS mounts` I have tried `rpcinfo -p` but still can't find the process.

Based on `netstat` output the pid is `33103` but `sudo lsof -p 33103` returns is empy.

Trying kill doesn't work:

```
$ kill -9 33103
kill: kill 33103 failed: no such process
```

Any ideas about how to find the process or close the port?